# Do we include operators in front of the coefficient when applying algebraic formulas to equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I'm doing some simple refresher on college algebra after a long time, but I've come to find some inconsistencies in my understanding of how to apply formulas, do we include operators in front of the coefficient when applying algebraic formulas to equations?

I'm struggling in particular with these two formulas:

**Quadratic formula, operators included here:**

$2x²+14x-196 = 0$, when applied to the formula $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b²- 4ac}}{2a}$, gives $\frac{-14\pm\sqrt{(14)^2-4(2)(-196)}}{2(2)}$. The answer here is $x = -14$, $x = 7$ [verified].

Notice that the coefficient "$c$" has to take on the negative operator infront of it to give the answer.

**However:**

If we be consistent and say yes, ***operators are to be included in formulas***:

When using the formula (what is this algebraic formula call btw?) $(a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2$ , when applied to $(2-3)^2$, gives: $2^2-2(2)(-3)+(-3)^2 = 4+12+9=25$. Which is clearly the wrong answer.

---

1) I'm struggling with this inconsistency, can anyone please help?

2) What is the general rule, when applying formulas, do we bring along operators in front of the number? (Yes/no)?

Comment: I removed the tags that had absolutely nothing to do with your question. Please read a tag description before using it.

Comment: What tags would you recommend for this @MartinArgerami?

Comment: The current tags are fine. The other two you had included. "Operator Algebras" and "Operator Theory" are about functional analysis and have no relation whatsoever with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ to $(2-3)^2$. Good, no ask yourself

1. What's $a$?
2. What's $b$?

Here $a=2$ and $b=3$.

You can't apply the formula with $a=2$ and $b=-3$, because $2-(-3)=2+3$.

Comment: Ok, sticking with that argument. Applying it to the quadratic formula; why is the "c" in 4ac, -196?  ie.−14±(14)2−4(2)(−196)√2(2)

Comment: @olif9837 It is $-196$, where's the problem? You can interpret $a-b$ either as a subtraction or as $a+(-b)$. The latter interpretation is the most used, for example in the case you mention.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to not think of negative signs as an operator in of itself but rather the negative sign being an indicator that you want to add the inverse of say $b$.

Then we have for example $(a-b)^{2} = (a+(-b))^{2} = a^{2} -2ab + b^{2}$. So we can see that $(a-b)^{2}$ is really just a special case of $(a+b)^{2}$.

**Edit:**

For further clarification, your quadratic formula example is completely consistent with the example above, since $c = (-196)$. Where the whole formula is then:

$ax^{2} + bx + c$ where $a = 2$, $b = 14$ and $c = (-196)$. Hope this helped.

Comment: "special case" does make it sound more reasonable, but pushes us to remember yet again a separate circumstance that doesn't apply consistently to all. If we _don't bring negative_ signs to the 2ab formula [ie. -2(2)(3)], why do we _bring negative signs_ to the 4ac formula [ie. -4(2)(-196)?

Comment: @olif9837 You have it mistaken. We always bring in negative signs to a formula. $(a + b) = (1 + 4) = 5$ if $a = 1$ and $b = 4$ but $(a + b) = (1 - 4) = -3 = (a - c)$ if $a = 1$, $b = (-3)$ and $c = 3$. Do you see the difference between the examples?